# Grab first item of array through custom content types manager

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress and Custom Content Types Manager, how do I go about editing the code below to only grab the first image from the array below?

```
    <?php
        $array_of_images = get_custom_field('slide_images:to_array');

        foreach ($array_of_images as $img_id) {
        ?>

        <div><?php print CCTM::filter($img_id, 'to_image_tag'); ?> </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

I tried adding in `array_slice($array_of_images, 0, 1);` but no luck so far. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what the returned array looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all else fails you could do the same as what you have except add an `$i` value. It's kind of dumb but it would work if you can't get a normal method to work. This would be a last ditch effort sort of thing...

```
<?php
        $array_of_images = get_custom_field('slide_images:to_array');

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($array_of_images as $img_id) { ?>

        <div><?php print CCTM::filter($img_id, 'to_image_tag'); ?> </div>

    <?php if($i == 0) break; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = array_keys($array_of_images);
$value = $array_of_images[$key[0]];
```